# PHP Print / Echo Back Arrow Error

Tags: php, mysql, xml, string

Used PHP for a few years now and come across a strange error today. Using a MySQL to produce an XML feed. The following keeps happening in output

```
<title>title</title>
<link>link</link>
<description>descriptiondescription>
```

When using print or echo the tag is missed on some of the feed ouput, here is the code.

```
    print "<description>";

    $desc = strip_tags($rowx['meta_description']);

    $desc = htmlspecialchars($desc);

    $desc = urlencode($desc);

    $desc = str_replace('%95', '', $desc);
    $desc = str_replace('%92', '', $desc);
    $desc = str_replace('%A3', '', $desc);

    $desc = urldecode($desc);

    print preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $desc );

    print "</description>";
    print "\n";
```

Another example of the output

```
<g:condition>new</g:condition>
<g:brand>SALTO</g:brand>
<g:color></g:color>
g:size></g:size>
<g:payment_accepted>Visa</g:payment_accepted>
```

Code which is outputting above

```
print "<g:condition>new</g:condition>";
        // print "\n";
        // brand 
        print "<g:brand>";
        $result_brand = mysql_query("SELECT value FROM cscart_product_features_values WHERE feature_id = '80' AND product_id = '$product_id'");
        $row_brand = mysql_fetch_row($result_brand);
        print $row_brand[0];
        print "</g:brand>";
        // print "\n";
        // color
        print "<g:color>";
        $result_color = mysql_query("SELECT cscart_product_feature_variant_descriptions.variant FROM cscart_product_feature_variant_descriptions, cscart_product_features_values WHERE cscart_product_feature_variant_descriptions.variant_id = cscart_product_features_values.variant_id AND cscart_product_features_values.feature_id = '19' AND product_id = '$product_id'");

        $row_color = mysql_fetch_row($result_color);
        print $row_color[0];

        print "</g:color>";
        // print "\n";
        // size
        print "<g:size>";
        $result_size = mysql_query("SELECT cscart_product_feature_variant_descriptions.variant FROM cscart_product_feature_variant_descriptions, cscart_product_features_values WHERE cscart_product_feature_variant_descriptions.variant_id = cscart_product_features_values.variant_id AND cscart_product_features_values.feature_id = '25' AND product_id = '$product_id'");

        $row_size = mysql_fetch_row($result_size);
        print $row_size[0];
        print "</g:size>";
        // print "\n";

        print "<g:payment_accepted>Visa</g:payment_accepted>";
```

Comment: Instead of preg_replace you might want to simply use `trim`.

Comment: How are we supposed to reply? You will have to give an example of what is contained in those variables. Most likely you cripple the url encoding with your strange replacements. Don't do that.

Comment: Why are you using URL encoding in XML? It's only intended for URL parameters or form input.

Comment: Please post the _input_ data that's producing these results.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code with the word "test" used instead of $rowx['meta_description'] and it worked... Could you please give the current 'meta_description' data for the case of failure?

Comment: I've just added another example with the full data

Comment: In your second example, the opening tag is damaged while in the first example the closing tag is damaged... so the damaged tag varies?

Comment: With your new code example I suggest you execute the SQL statements "by hand" and check the data that is output. Maybe it contains characters that are interpret as control characters when output via `print` ...